# Select element is not posting data on form submit

Tags: php, html, forms, drop-down-menu, materialize

I've created a simple contact form using materialize framework and it seems that select element is not posting data upon a form submit cause whenever I check the posted value it's empty. Do you have any ideas how to handle this problem? Thanks

Here is my form code:

```
<form class="col s12 m12 l12" id="contact-form" method="post" action="php/send_form_email.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
            <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" name="first_name" class="validate" required>
            <label for="icon_prefix">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" name="email" required>
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
            <select name="traffic" required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>Choose your option</option>
                <option value="youtube">YouTube</option>
                <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
                <option value="google search">Google search</option>
            </select>
            <label>How did you know about us?</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="submit-btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn z-depth-0" type="submit" value="Submit">submit</button>
    <button id="reset-btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn z-depth-0" type="reset">reset</button>
</form>
```

Here is my send_form_email.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "info@abcd.com";
    $email_subject = "Request";
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $traffic = $_POST['traffic']; // required
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Traffic source: ".$traffic."\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Go to the network tab in the browser console, is it sending this parameter?

Comment: You are not ending your `if(isset($_POST[‘email’])` condition. You closed the function bracket but not the `if`

Comment: Network monitor shows that no data has been sent from select element and that's strange. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

it's materialize bug [Materialize Issue](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5564). If you can use Jquery or JS, you can solve it for now by adding hidden input and change its value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="select_name">
<select id="select_input">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Choose opt</option>
 <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
</select>

<script>
 $("#select_input").on('change', function () {
  $("input[value='select_name']").val($(this).val());
 })
</script>
```

or you can use `class="browser-default"` but there is also Issue [Browser default Issue](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5556)